# Tomcat directory to save information across restarts and redeployment

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I have the requirement to save some information across restarts and redeployments, i.e. write it to a file when Tomcat is shut down and restore it from the file when it is started. It's similar to the way Tomcat saves session information across restarts (see [Persistence Across Restarts](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Persistence_Across_Restarts)).

- What's the correct directory for such a file?
- What's the API to get the path to this directory?

I'm looking for a solution that works on different operation systems, works across redeployments and does not require any setup or configuration tasks. It should be as simple as Tomcat's session persistence, which just works without any configuration.

Comment: have you needed info about where file reside ? or only need logic ? I mean, i understood that file can be anywhere inside tomcat then ti's fine?

Comment: I'm just looking for the proper location and the Java code to get the path to that location. I know how and when to write and read the file.

Comment: If you are saving something in a file, you can save it at multiple locations on your servers file-system. How is tomcat related to this? One can create a file in Downloads directory as well and read it after restart. Java has many api's to read/write to text files.

Comment: As it is related to my web application, I would like to save it close to the web server / servlet container. And it should work on different operations systems and I don't want to configure a path in each installation of my web app.

Comment: "What's the correct directory for such a file?" - obviously a directory where the user that runs Tomcat is allowed to write files. Generally you create such a directory yourself, or a system administrator does it for you.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution without any manual work involved whatsoever, in particular without creating a directory or configuring a path. But I'd like to take advantage of Tomcat as I know my web application will always be run in Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ServletContextListener - Interface` For handling your backup plan.

```
ServletContextListener - contextDestroyed(..) & contextInitialized(..)
```

And for Handling Path while store file inside Tomcat-server,
Use this code for retrieving path, `request.getRealPath("/").toString()`

Above getRealPath("/") will provide you server's log directory path. please change it accordingly whatever nearest you want.

Let me know whether this help in your scenario or not ?

Comment: I'm afraid this solution doesn't work. It basically returns the path to the expanded war file contents. If the war file is not expanded, you cannot write to the directory. And even if it's expanded, it will be destroyed on redeployment, which is a problem for me.

Comment: can you use Database on behalf of file-system ?

Comment: A database would involve configuration. And I'm looking for a configuration free setup.

Comment: @Codo, as i understand your requirement then, you want some value should be remain inside file, which file must be presented where your war was deployed. so doesn't make sent above my trick, if i am understand wrongly then please make me correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. I'm trying to save data of my web application that should persist across Tomcat restarts and redeployments of my web application. And I hope to find a solution that works without setup or configuration. Therefore, a good place would be somewhere within the Tomcat installation but outside my web application.

Comment: BTW: Your approach with the ServletContextListener is exactly what I'm planning. My only problem is to find a suitable directory.

Comment: @Codo, As per my suggestion, you would be able to get location of your application where you have deployed. can't you take any other directory which will relative to that location also that wasn't deleting anything while redeployment.

Comment: If the war file is not exploded, getRealPath() will return something like "jar:...". You cannot create a relative path from there.